# Spring boot embedded tomcat server take over 800 MB RAM?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot

I'm working on a Springboot application that uses embedded tomcat server. Application take more than 800MB RAM. Is that common? Is there any way to bring memory uses down?

Answer (score 2):

The amount of memory consumed by your tomcat totally depends upon your application requirement.
You need to do some sort of memory profiling of your application.

> Is that common?

Yes, I could be. It all depends on your application, the way you create objects and the amount of memory being used by your objects.

You can start with putting your -Xms to 1GB and run your application and perform normal operations.
Use tools like [JVisualVm](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/jvisualvm.html) or [JConsole](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html) to observe the Heap Size and GC performance and even amount of memory consumed by different types of objects in the JVM.

This will give you an intial idea abount amount of Heap required by your application. 
After this use tool like [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) to load test your application check how the load is hampering your heap usage.

Suggested Reading:
http://blog.manupk.com/2012/09/java-memory-model-simplified.html

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common. Java VMs are pretty heavy. Look at the JVM start up flags, which will tell you what the heapsize can grow to (You may see something like `-Xmx768m` which allocates a maximum of 768M of heap). You might try setting the `CATALINA_OPTS` environment variable: `CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx512m`, but if the springboot script that boots the VM overrides this you will have to track down the value being set in the script. However, the default value generally works well and will prevent the JVM from throwing out of memory errors if you start instantiating many or large (read: hibernate) objects that take a while to be garbage collected.

Comment: *"-Xmx768m which allocates 768M of heap"* -  Actually, that is setting the maximum heap size.  The heap will only grow to that size if the application requires it.   The "heavyness" of a JVM depends largely on what you are running.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to bring memory uses down?

There are two approaches:

- You can attempt to "squeeze" the heap size.  That is not recommended, as it leads to the JVM spending a larger percentage of the CPU in the GCs, more frequent GC pauses, and ultimately OOMEs.

  This approach often doesn't work at all; i.e. it just causes the application to die quicker.
- You can figure out why your application is using so much memory.  It could be due to many things:

  - The problem may be too big.
  - Your application could be "bloated" with all sorts of unnecessary libraries, features, etc.
  - Your in-memory data structures could be poorly designed.
  - Your application could be caching too much in memory.
  - Your application could have memory leaks.

I agree with @cowbert's advice.  Use performance monitoring tools to try to track down what is using most of the JVM's memory.  If there is a memory leak, this often shows up as an unexpectedly large amount of memory used for certain kinds of objects.